# Active Reports 7 Make texboxes resize together

Tags: report, activereports

How can I make textboxes resize together when one of them word wraps. I am using borders and I need to texboxes to be the same size so the borders line up correctly. Im using Active Reports 7 and have a sub report that contains several textbox controls aligned beside each other horizontally. Like so.

```
[Textbox1    ][Textbox2    ][Textbox3    ][Textbox4    ]
```

When textbox1 word wraps I end up with something like this

```
[Textbox1....][Textbox2    ][Textbox3     ][Textbox4    ]
[..2nd line. ]
```

Ive tried setting the textbox sizes in the format event but that doesnt work. Because the texboxes havent resized yet.

```
Private Sub Detail1_Format(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Detail1.Format
    'Resize all the texboxes so when the description WordWraps all the other texbox borders line up correctly.
TextBox1.Height = TextBox1.Height
TextBox2.Height = TextBox1.Height
TextBox3.Height = TextBox1.Height
TextBox4.Height = TextBox1.Height
TextBox5.Height = TextBox1.Height
TextBox6.Height = TextBox1.Height
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get the correct results if you use the "Format" event to set the height of the other textboxes in accordance to the first textbox height. I would suggest you to rather use the "BeforePrint" event to set the height.

```
public void Detail_BeforePrint()
{
    this.TextBox2.Height = this.TextBox1.Height;    
    this.TextBox3.Height = this.TextBox1.Height;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sankalp is correct that you should use the BeforePrint event as the height is not determined yet in the Format event.

His answer works great if you know the TextBox1 height is always the largest. However, if you do not know the height of the largest textbox, then you can just set everything to detail's height.

```
public void Detail_BeforePrint()
{
    this.TextBox1.Height = Detail.Height;
    this.TextBox2.Height = Detail.Height;
    this.TextBox3.Height = Detail.Height;
}
```

Using this method, you'll never need to come back to refactor the height.